# C# Get List<object> distinct id and value as dictionary (duplicate items in list)

Tags: c#, dictionary

Let's assume I have a class:

```
public class Demo
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

and then a list of Demo

```
List<Demo> demo = new List<Demo>();
```

the list contains many items, and many of them are duplicates.

example

```
 Item1:
     Id= 1;
     Value = "Something"

 Item2:
     Id= 2;
     Value = "Something else"

 Item3:
     Id= 3;
     Value = "Something else in here"

 Item4:
     Id= 1;
     Value = "Something"
```

................

```
 ItemN:
     Id= 2;
     Value = "Something else"
```

As you can see above there are few identical items (same id and value).

Now what I need is to convert this to a `Dictionary<string,string>` obviously getting rid of duplicates.

BTW the `Id` is the field that define the item duplicate.

EDIT:

I've tried to group the list by ID but I don't know how to get the value also and make it Dictionary

```
var grouped= demo.GroupBy(t => t.Id).ToList();
```

Now I can do `grouped.Key` and I have the ID but how can I get the value?

Comment: _"the Id is the field that define the item duplicate"_ is it only the id or the combination of Id and Value?

Comment: Just the ID, the value is 99.9% the same but you never know, however the ID is the one to check if it's duplicate or not

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var idLookup = demo.ToLookup(d => d.Id);
```

Now you can get all items for a given `ID` in this way:

```
IEnumerable<Demo> demoWithId2 = idLookup["2"];
```

If it doesn't contain this Id the sequence is empty(`demoWithId2.Any() == false`).

If you want the number of distinct ID's:

```
int numberOfDistinctIDs = idLookup.Count;
```

If you want the number of values per ID:

```
int numberOfDemoWithId2  = idLookup["2"].Count();
```

If you want a `List<Demo>` with an arbitrary object(the first) for each ID:

```
demo = idLookup.Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just the ID, the value is 99.9% the same but you never know, however
>   the ID is the one to check if it's duplicate or not

Use `GroupBy` to get distinct values based on `Id` and then get the first object from the group and get its value in `ToDictionary` like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = demo.GroupBy(d => d.Id)
                    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First().Value);
```

This will get the `Value` from the first grouped element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
lst.GroupBy (l => l.Id)
    .Select (g => lst.First (l => l.Id==g.Key))
    .ToDictionary (l => l.Id, l=>l.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `Demo` class inherit from `IEquatable` and have it implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` like so:

```
public class Demo : IEquatable<Demo>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Demo other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) 
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) 
            return true;
        return other.Id == Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call `.Distinct()` on your `List` then convert to a `Dictionary` like this:

```
List<Demo> demo = new List<Demo>
{
    new Demo { Id = "1", Value = "Something" },
    new Demo { Id = "2", Value = "Something else" },
    new Demo { Id = "3", Value = "Something else in here" },
    new Demo { Id = "1", Value = "Something" },
};

Dictionary<string, string> demoDictionary = demo.Distinct().ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Value);
demoDictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", k, demoDictionary[k]));
```

Results:

```
Key: 1 Value: Something
Key: 2 Value: Something else
Key: 3 Value: Something else in here
```